# MySQL After Insert Trigger with Variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've created this trigger, but I have two problems. One it does not actively populate the Person table and two. If I enter more than one row into my Party table I get an error in access, Result of Subquery returns more than one row.
Anybody know my problem(s)?

```
DELIMITER $$
Create TRIGGER Trigger1

  AFTER
  INSERT
  ON Party
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

declare partytypeid  int;
declare partyid  int;

set @partyid:= (select partyid from party);
set @partytypeid:= (select partytypeid from party);

      IF partytypeid = 1 
        THEN  INSERT INTO Person
        (PartyId) VALUES (PartyId);
        END IF;    

    END$$
    delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set your variables, you're doing a select against the whole table instead of the inserted record.

```
DELIMITER $$ 

Create TRIGGER Trigger1

AFTER INSERT ON Party FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    declare partytypeid int; 
    declare partyid int;

    set @partyid:= new.partyid; 
    set @partytypeid:= new.partytypeid;
    IF partytypeid = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO Person
        (PartyId) VALUES (PartyId);
    END IF;    

END$$
delimiter ;
```